# curl_exec dies with error 500, while uploading to s3

Tags: php, post, curl

I am uploading a large file with curl (php) to amazon s3, using POST request.
When the file is small (several MBs) - it works. When the file is couple of hundred MB - the script dies with error 500 at the `curl_exec` line (I know it exactly, because I have placed logging right before and after it).

The curl initialization looks like

```
$postdata = array_merge( $headers_array , array('file' => '@' . $filename));           
$curl_handle = curl_init();         
curl_setopt( $curl_handle , CURLOPT_URL , $s3_url );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 ); 
curl_setopt( $curl_handle , CURLOPT_POST , TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle , CURLOPT_HEADER , FALSE );
curl_setopt ($curl_handle , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

$response = curl_exec( $curl_handle ); 
`500 here`
```

I assume, that the problem is out of memory (or something alike). I have requested my hosting provider to show me the error_log, but maybe there is something I could do now.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your own server is die()ing with 500 error, you may be running out of memory, try these steps.

Since you can't view your errorlog, ensure errors are output from your script file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Increase the memory limit in your php.ini, or preferably, do not load the entire file into memory before sending it (give curl a file pointer, not the entire file content).

An example can be seen in this excellent PHP S3 library:

[Amazon S3 PHP Class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class)

If it's Amazon returning a 500 error, this would be the method to determine why:

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error):
Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has encountered an error or is otherwise incapable of performing the request. Except when responding to a HEAD request, **the server should include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation**, and indicate whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

Output the response header and the response body to look for a description of the reason:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$responseBody = curl_exec($curl_handle);
echo $responseBody;
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_handle));
```

The cause should be mentioned in there somewhere.

Comment: curl_exec does not return anything, and no line after it is executed.  The server just dies with error 500

Comment: Ahh your server dies with 500, S3 is not returning a 500 error?

Comment: If that's the case, that seems to be a problem encountered by others here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=249349 Though there is no solution for his particular case, the steps he outlines are valid and may resolve the problem for you.

Comment: This is a good idea. I will try it and get back to you. Thank you